# Why is my fibonacci Generator returning undefined when it's ran

Tags: javascript

I am creating a fibonacci Generator that will return an array as an output when the function is called. For example, if I call the function "fibonacciGenerator(3)"  the output should be an array of  [0, 1, 1].  I keep getting undefined when the code is ran. Why do I keep getting undefined? What is the best way to approach this problem?

```
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

    //starting fibonacci array from 0 and 1
    var fib = [0,1]; 


for (var i = 0; i < fib.length; i++) {

  if(fib[i] === 2){
      //add the two preceding numbers to get sum. Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2
     var Fn = fib[i -1] + fib[i -2];
     console.log(Fn);                 
  }
}

    //Return an array of fibonacci numbers.
    return Fn;
}


fibonacciGenerator (3);
```

Comment: TL;DR - your code is not even close to being a fibonacci generator .... `return Fn;` ... did yo mean `return fib;` also, you never ADD to any array anywhere, therefore you can never return an array of Fibonacci numbers ... also, your loop only goes as long as the existing fib array, so fib[i] can never === 2 therefore Fn is never defined, hence it is undefined - and you make no refernce to `n` so, why pass it in?

Comment: When will this be true? `fib[i] === 2`

Comment: Arrays start at zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` is because `Fn` never gets declared because `if(fib[i] === 2)`.You can do this following steps.

- Initialize an array as `[0,1]`
- Create a loop that will run `n-2` times
- In each loop get the sum of the last two elements of current array i.e `fib`
- Add that sum to the last of the array using `push()`

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
    //initializing the array to first two number of sequence
    var fib = [0,1]; 
    //Running loop n-2 times
    for (var i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
        //Adding the sum of last two elements of the array to end of array. 
        fib.push(fib[fib.length - 1] + fib[fib.length - 2]);            
    }
    return fib;
}


console.log(fibonacciGenerator(3));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong logic. Push the addition to the array and do not create new variable for that, Remove the if statement it is having wrong condition and start the for loo from 2

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  //starting fibonacci array from 0 and 1
  var fib = [0, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++)
    //add the two preceding numbers to get sum. Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2
    fib.push(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
}
//Return an array of fibonacci numbers.
return fib;
}
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(7));
```